# How to open multiple local HTML files in Google Chrome at once?

Tags: windows, windows-8, google-chrome, html-files

Using Google Chrome Dev Channel on Windows, I have multiple local HTML files in one folder:

[image: directory contents]

And I want to open them all at once in one Google Chrome window as separate tabs:

[image: google chrome with multiple tabs]

What I tried and did *not* succeed:

- Selecting all files in Windows Explorer and dragging them into Chrome (only one file was opened)
- Selecting all files in Windows Explorer and right-clicking then "Open" (a blank new Chrome window opened)
- Selecting all files in Windows Explorer and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> (a blank new Chrome window opened)
- Using the file open dialog in Chrome (only single selection supported)

So what seemed to be a trivial task to me seems to actually be impossible.

How can I open multiple local HTML files at once in Google Chrome?

Comment: Please do not edit answer into your question. Instead, you can post another answer for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the best solution, but it worked for me. [This was previously answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14371711).

You can just create a new text file and change the file extension to .bat then type something like this:

```
start chrome.exe http://www.google.com
start chrome.exe file-path-here    
start chrome.exe another-file-here
```

Then all you have to do is double click that file and they'll all open up in different tabs.

Comment: This helped me greatly. I even modified it into a subprocess method using python. I explained how I leveraged this in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63749975/996205

Answer (score 14):

You can achieve this by adding Chrome to "Send to" and then "sending" your desktop files/images there.

Comment: add short cut to chrome to "send to" by dragging & dropping the chrome link to this folder %AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo

Comment: Awesome! This is the best solution so far! Works in Windows 10.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 5):

You can drag and drop multiple HTML files on a shortcut to Chrome (on the Desktop for instance) to open all those files in new tabs in the browser. Alternatively, you can open the Chrome installation folder (possibly `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application`) in another Windows Explorer and drop your file directly on the `chrome.exe` executable.

Note that this does not work on icon of pinned software in the Taskbar on Windows 8+ (but it will probably work on a shortcut in a custom toolbar).

Comment: +1 - this also conveniently works on Macs

Answer (score 3):

This is what I came up with:

```
forfiles /M *.html /C "cmd /c start chrome @file"
```

Yes… this is the actual syntax (sadly) you would use from the directory which contains the files. Simply hold shift and right click in your explorer window to select `Open command window here` from the context menu, and toss in this command to open files at your leisure.

[Here is a link to more information on the command.](http://ss64.com/nt/for2.html)

Answer (score 2):

On Linux, you can just put all your files as arguments in the command line. In the folder where your files are:

```
google-chrome file1.html file2.html
google-chrome *.html
```

This will open the files as separate tabs in the browser.